# Function returns a weird value

Tags: python, function, converters

I made this simple conversion function using Python a while ago, but now as I went over it, I just noticed how it returns: `100 * 8.8 = 880.0000000000001`. It works when using any other values such as `10`, `1000`, etc. Could somebody please explain this to me?

```
def converting_currency(usd):
    currency = input("What currency do you have? ('KR' or 'EU')")
    if currency == 'KR':
        amount = usd * 8.8
        print("If you have", + usd, "dollars, you have", + amount, "kronor")

    elif currency == 'EU':
        amount = usd * 10.5
        print("If you have", + usd, "euros, you have", + amount, "kronor")
converting_currency(100)
```

It returns:

```
What currency do you have? ('KR' or 'EU')KR
If you have 100 dollars, you have 880.0000000000001 kronor

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Look at [floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: obligatory [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)